# Method threw java.io.EOFException on Redis-Based Tomcat Session Management

Tags: spring, session, tomcat, jsf, redis

I have used Redis-Based Tomcat Session Management for Session Clustering between my two servers. So that one server goes down another server can pick up the session and continue serving client request.The biggest challenge here is to serialize all the properties in all the classes having scope as session or request else it will end on `NotSerializableException`. But i have manged to solve almost all the serialize exceptions and application started working. But now I am facing a strange issue, that if i navigate to some pages and click command links or buttons then its simply throws the exception and it wont't show any `NotSerializableException` also.

While debugging throw my ViewHandler class i have found that  `javax.faces.FacesException` exception coming when trying to execute `parent.restoreView(facesContext, viewId)` in the below code.

```
public class CustomViewHandler extends ViewHandler {
    private ViewHandler parent;

    public CustomViewHandler(ViewHandler parent) {
        //System.out.println("CustomViewHandler.CustomViewHandler():Parent View Handler:"+parent.getClass());
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override public UIViewRoot restoreView(FacesContext facesContext, String viewId) {
        /**
         * {@link javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException}. This happens only  when we try to logout from timed out pages.
         */
        UIViewRoot root =null;
        root = parent.restoreView(facesContext, viewId);
        if(root == null) {
            root = createView(facesContext, viewId);
        }
        return root;
    }   ......
```

This is working fine if i disable the Redis session management or If i put all the `Autowired` interfaces into `transient` in the backing bean of that page. From the stack trace i cannot point out any `Serializable` related issue also. But the interfaces used in such bean i made into `Serializable` so i don't understand why i need to put `transient` for all the `Autowired` interfaces. With out adding `transient` everywhere how can i solve this exception.

Stack trace of FacesException:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet faces threw exception
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at org.drools.common.DroolsObjectInputStream.<init>(DroolsObjectInputStream.java:55)
    at org.drools.common.DroolsObjectInputStream.<init>(DroolsObjectInputStream.java:49)
    at org.drools.common.AbstractRuleBase.readExternal(AbstractRuleBase.java:232)
    at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooRuleBase.readExternal(ReteooRuleBase.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.readObject(AdvisedSupport.java:550)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.readObject(AdvisedSupport.java:550)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.readObject(AdvisedSupport.java:550)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.readObject(AdvisedSupport.java:550)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.readObject(AdvisedSupport.java:550)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.handleRestoreState(AjaxStateManager.java:375)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.restoreView(AjaxStateManager.java:449)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.restoreView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:318)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.restoreView(FaceletViewHandler.java:316)
    at com.erp.core.ui.CustomViewHandler.restoreView(CustomViewHandler.java:24)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.restoreView(PrettyViewHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.restoreView(FaceletViewHandler.java:316)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:104)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at com.erp.security.acegi.CustomLogoutFilter.doFilter(CustomLogoutFilter.java:32)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.erp.security.HttpThreadLogFilter.doFilter(HttpThreadLogFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at com.erp.security.acegi.CustomLogoutFilter.doFilter(CustomLogoutFilter.java:32)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at com.bluejeans.tomcat.redissessions.RedisSessionHandlerValve.invoke(RedisSessionHandlerValve.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:319)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: So the code where the NPE is thrown is irrelevant? It looks to be your code.

Comment: Yes, But got nothing from the trace to track the issue. So is there anything that i can do to find where is the issue in my code

Comment: Weird argumenting. As it stands, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it is a duplicate of your question.

Comment: What's the stack trace of that `FacesException` then? Isn't it actually a `ViewExpiredException`?

Comment: @BalusC stack trace of the FacesException added. It seems not a ViewExpiredException because i have added enableRestoreView11Compatibility also but no change

Comment: So effectively your title is wrong... In reality there is a EOF Exception when drools is trying to read something. Maybe the JSF tag should be replaced with a drools one?

Comment: I suspect you made something transient to get it into the session that should not be transient but serialized and with 99% certainty it is related to drools.

Comment: @BalusC after changing the savestate from server to client. I am getting `NullPointerException` instead for `java.util.PropertyResourceBundle.handleGetObject(PropertyResourceBundle.java:155)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:389)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:355)
        at java.util.logging.Formatter.formatMessage(Formatter.java:118)
        at java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format(SimpleFormatter.java:151)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.publish(FileHandler.java:285)`